# MetadataTypeAttribute not adorning additional attributes to properties

Tags: c#, attributes, metadata, code-generation

I have a code generated class that has a set of attributes on properties. I would like to add additional attributes to these properties but I cannot do that on the code generated class. Therefore I make use of the `MetadataTypeAttribute` to adorn additional attributes from an auxiliary class;

```
// Code generated class - can't touch this
public partial class MyClass
{
    public MyType MyProperty { get; set; }
}

// Partial class allowing extended attributes
[MetadataType(typeof(MyClass_AdditionalAttributes))]
public partial class MyClass
{
}

// Defines extra attributes to be appended to
// properties that match in the partial class
public class MyClass_AdditionalAttributes
{
    // Do not serialise the MyProperty property
    [XmlIgnore]
    public MyType MyProperty;
}
```

However, this does not work. Using .NET reflector, the `XmlIgnoreAttribute` is not adorned to the `MyClass.MyProperty` property. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with *ScriptIgnore* instead of *XMLIgnore*) and couldn't make it work. In the end I made the designer property private and defined the public property in an external partial class with the attributes I wanted, just getting and setting the private one.